# NodeJS : Delete array items using an async operation one by one

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I need to operate on each item of an array and that operation is an async one. I need to proceed to the next item only when the first one is processed. I need to return true if all items are processed.
This piece of code should itself be a promise that I can chain on to.

This is what I tried doing :

```
deleteAll(items) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        items.forEach(async element => {
            await this.deleteOne(element); //Async delete operation
            items.shift();
            if(items.length-1==index)   resolve(true)
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `Promise.all` if you want to check if all the operations have ended, so you don't have to track all the async operations yourself.

```
async deleteAll(items) {
    await Promise.all(
       items.map(element => this.deleteOne(element))
    );
    items.splice(0, items.length); // clear items
}
```

Your code won't work, because it will trigger when the last item in the array is removed, which not necessarily will be the last item removed from your database.

If you want to run it sequentially, instead of using `Promise.all` you can use a simple `for of` loop

```
async deleteAll(items) {
    for(const item of items)
       await this.deleteOne(item);
    // I'm done with all the items
    items.splice(0, items.length);
}
```

Don't forget to `.catch` any rejection:

```
deleteAll([1,2]).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Or `try/catch` if it's inside an `async` function, and you're using `await`.

Comment: Thanks! 
Like I mentioned, I want to call the deleteOne method second time only when the first occurrence has completed and not in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a good old for loop:

```
async function deleteAll(items) {
  for(const el of items) {
    await this.deleteOne(el);
  }
  items.splice(0, items.length);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this:

```
async deleteAll(items) {
  for(let element of items) {
    await this.deleteOne(element);
  }
  items.length = 0
}
```

Your code might work as long as `this.deleteOne` resolves successfully. But if `this.deleteOne` fails and this Promise is rejected, then you will an unhandled rejection.

And an unhandled rejection will crash your whole node application in future versions.

Creating a new Promise  (`new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ .. }`) and using another Promise withing that newly created Promise always indicates that you do something wrong.